# How to get ISO Country code in android applications?

Tags: android, mobile, code-generation, country

I am a new developer on android application. I would like to get the ISO Country code when I pass the mobile number with country code. If I pass the mobile number as 1-319-491-6338, can I get country ISO code as US / USA in android?

I have written the code as follows:

```
      TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      String countryCode = tm.getSimCountryIso();
      String mobileno="1-319-491-6338";
```

Here, where can I pass the mobile number?

Can anybody please help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might not be as simple as you think.  Take a look at this site: http://countrycode.org/.  They are listing at least 2 different countries with telephone code `1`.  How would you decide which one in this case?

Comment: String countryCode = tm.getSimCountryIso();
 this line itself giving ISO code as US

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may not be able to query the country code programmatically via the standard API but you could include a table in your app. Such a table is easily found via Google (e.g. http://countrycode.org/).

**Danger Will Robinson!**: However, one should ask yourself what question you are trying to answer. Implicit in your question is that assumption that there is a one-to-one mapping between international dialling codes and ISO country codes. This is **not** true. For example, both the USA and Canada have the international dialling code '1'.

Perhaps think about re-structuring your app's interface. Allow the user to select a country to associate with the phone number but use the table from http://countrycode.org/ to order the most likely candidates at the top?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Eventually I put all the data in excel and read the excel sheet.
Here is the implementation:

1. copy-past the country code table from http://countrycode.org/ to Microsoft Excel file.
2. Save the Excel file as 97-2003 compatible (.xls) in \res\raw\countrycode_org.xls
3. Download [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/jexcelapi/2.6.12/)
4. Use the following class to read the file:

   public class CountryCodes {
           private HashMap mCountryByName = new HashMap();
           private HashMap mCountryByCode = new HashMap();;
           private ArrayList mCountries = new ArrayList();

   ```
   public void addCountry(String countryName,String ISO_code,String countryCode){
       countryCode = PhoneNumberUtil.normalizeDigitsOnly(countryCode);
       Country country = new Country();
       country.Name = countryName;
       country.Code = countryCode;
       country.ISO_code = ISO_code;
       mCountryByName.put(countryName, country);
       mCountryByCode.put(countryCode, country);
       mCountries.add(country);

       return;
   }

   public Country getCountryByCode(String countryCode){
       countryCode = PhoneNumberUtil.normalizeDigitsOnly(countryCode);
       return mCountryByCode.get(countryCode);
   }

   public Country getCountryByName(String countryName){
       return mCountryByName.get(countryName);
   }

   public Country getCountryByIsoCode(String ISO_code){
       ISO_code = ISO_code.toUpperCase();
       for (Country country:mCountries){
           String [] strArr = country.ISO_code.split("/| ");
           for (String s:strArr){
               if (ISO_code.equals(s))
                   return country;
           }
       }
       return null;
   }



   public  String[] getCountryNamesList(){
       String[] res = new String [mCountries.size()];
       int i=0;
       for (Country c:mCountries){
           res[i] = c.Name;
           i++;
       }
       return res;
   }



   public void readCountryCodesFromExcelWorkbook()
   {
       Context context = GlobalData.getInstance().getApp();
       Workbook mWorkbook;
       InputStream myRawResource = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.countrycode_org);
       if (myRawResource == null)
           Toast.makeText(context,"XML file not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       else
           try {
               WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
               ws.setEncoding("Cp1252");

               mWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(myRawResource);
                   //ArrayList<String[]> currentSheet = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                   Sheet sheet = mWorkbook.getSheet(0);

                   int rowsNum = sheet.getRows();
                   for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum < rowsNum; rowNum++) {
                       //Log.d("RowNum", ""+rowNum);
                       int colsNum = sheet.getColumns();
                       String[] strArr = new String[colsNum];
                       boolean rowIsFull = true;
                       for (int colNum = 0; colNum < colsNum; colNum++) {
                           strArr[colNum] = sheet.getCell(colNum, rowNum).getContents();
                           if (strArr[colNum].length() == 0)
                               rowIsFull = false;
                       }
                       if (rowIsFull)
                           addCountry(strArr[0],strArr[1],strArr[2]);
                   }


           } catch (BiffException e) {
               Toast.makeText(context,"Error Reading xml file: BiffException",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               e.printStackTrace();
               return ;
           } catch (IOException e) {
               Toast.makeText(context,"Error Reading xml file: IOException",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               e.printStackTrace();
               return ;
           }
   }


   public Country[] getCountries(){
       return mCountries.toArray(new Country[0]);
   }



   public class Country {
       public String Name;
       public String Code;
       public String ISO_code;

   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1**
You can get `country calling code` as well as its `ISO name` in the following URL
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes

or

http://www.unc.edu/~rowlett/units/codes/country.htm

**Step-2** You can get page source of that file using java program. You will get file in HTMl format

**Step-3** you can convert those HTML files into XML format using any of available parsers. see [Open Source HTML Parsers in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)

**Step-4** Form the phone number you can get the calling code. Example if the number is "1-319-491-6338" then calling code is 1

**Step-5** Match this calling code against the calling code and country name list that you have got from XML parser. In this way you can get iso country